# How to use current scope for custom builder class methods via ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

I have many `Messages` on each `Account`, and want to use a custom builder like so: `Account.find(x).messages.send_and_create('confirm')`.

To do that, I need access to the `account_id` value within `send_and_create` to set the value when building the `message`. Yet I am unable to find a way to write this class method on `Message` to get that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Association Extensions are the way to solve this:

```
has_many :messages do 
  def send_and_create(type)
    ...
  end
end
```

[Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/30ea1a70cba1124893b2479cb7f277cb260ddfcd/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1149)